# Subtract 2 Pandas Dataframes retrieving "NaN"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have 2 pandas dataframes.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1],'c2':[2],'c3':[2],'c4':[1],'c5':[1],'c6':[1]}) 

B = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0],'c2':[1],'c3':[0],'c4':[1],'c5':[0],'c6':[1]})
```

I would like to subtract B to A and assign the difference to A.
I tried several options wither using the assign subtraction or pandas subtraction functions, but don't seem to get the right values.

Either get "NaN" when subtracting and assigning or the wrong data.

I tried:

```
A.sub(B, fill_value=0)
```

and

```
A-=B
```

I expect, after this iteration, to get a new A dataframe [1 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 1 , 0 ].

Any ideas?

Comment: I get the correct results when I use both of these.  Are the columns in both frames, as well as the index identical?

Comment: Is this exact example result in a nan on your end? What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @user3483203,  the column types are the same

Answer (score 0):

Just use subtract

```
A.subtract(B).fillna(0)
  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
  0   1   1   2   0   1   0
```

Comment: On my end, `A-B` gives the same results as `A.subtract(B)`. Does the OP's example reproduce on your end?

Comment: Here first 0 is the index

Comment: Yes, indeed, well, I keep getting the NaN's using this method

Comment: @PrathikKini yes I did tried that but it doesn't quite work either