# Subtract in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to know how `subtract` works

```
target_df = df.subtract(df1)
```

Either it should return the rows that are not in `df1` to `target_df` or it will return `df` rows that are not in `df1` to `target_df`

Comment: From the [documentation for `subtract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract): *Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this frame but not in another frame.*

Comment: Also, you can just try it out with a small example and see what happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461787/subtract-2-pandas-dataframes-retrieving-nan

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume below example:

```
df1 has values as (1,2,3,4,5,6)
df2 has values as (3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Then target_df=df1.subtract(df2) will have the values as 'values in df1 - common values in both dfs' i.e.

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6) - (3,4,5,6) = (1,2)
```

Please run below code for the same:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(1), Row(2), Row(3), Row(4), Row(5), Row(6)]).toDF()
df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(3), Row(4), Row(5), Row(6), Row(7), Row(8)]).toDF()
target_df = df1.subtract(df2)
target_df.show()
```